# How to monitor SQL (which uses prepared stataments)?

Tags: php, mysql, odbc, prepared-statement, database-tools

When first developing an PHP app (MySQl, but using ODBC interfaces to allow for future expansion), I was simply assigning my SQL to a variable and calling `odbc_exec()`.

That made debugging simple, as I just had to examine my variable `$sql`.

Of course, I soon realized that I have to use prepared statements to sanitize user input.

My question is how to discover the exact SQL which is being executed in the databse, in order to debug my prepared statements.

I reazlise that I can't do it from PHP, but are their any external monitor tools which can interecpt the SQL? Or even a MySql command to echo, if I leave a console window open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MySQL [query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can start mysql server by `--log[=file_name]` to have a log file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I cam up with to aid debugging within PHP code.

However, to be absolutely certin of what is being executed by MySql, the other posters are correct. Look at the query log.

```
function OdbcPrepareAndExecute($sql, $parameter_array)
{
   if (substr_count($sql, '?') != count($parameter_array))
   {
      ob_start();
      var_dump($parameter_array);
      $parameter_array_dump .= ob_get_clean();

      ReportErrorAndDie('Invalid parameters', 
                        'Request to prepare ODBC statement "' . $sql .'" with ' .
                        substr_count($sql, '?') . ' place-holders, but ' . 
                        count($parameter_array) . ' parameters in array : ' .
                        $parameter_array_dump
                       );
   }


   LogDatabaseActivity('Prepare SQL "' . $sql . '"');

   $prepared_statement = @odbc_prepare($_SESSION['connection'], $sql);
   if($prepared_statement === False) 
   {
      ReportErrorAndDie('Database problem', 
                        'Could not prepare ODBC statement "' . $sql .'"');
   }

   LogDatabaseActivity('Execute prepared SQL statement with the following parameters:');
   ob_start();
   var_dump($parameter_array);
   $parameter_array_dump = ob_get_clean();
   LogDatabaseActivity($parameter_array_dump);

   $expanded_sql = $sql;
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($parameter_array); $i++)
   $expanded_sql = substr_replace($expanded_sql, 
                                  $parameter_array[$i], 
                                  strpos($expanded_sql, '?'), 
                                  1);

   LogDatabaseActivity('(preapred statement expands to "' . $expanded_sql . '")');

   $result = @odbc_execute($prepared_statement, $parameter_array);
```